# Dúvida sobre botão radio

Tags: php, if, radiobutton

Tenho um formulário que tem dois botões `radio`: 1-masc 2-fem.

Quero que quando um deles tiver apertado, e eu clicar em "calcular" ele puxe o `if` indicado para cada `radio`.

```
     <form name="calc" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">

         <input type="radio" name="masc" value="masc" id="masc" />
         <input type="radio" name="femi" value="femi" id="femi" />
     <input type="text" id="Idade" name="idade" required="">
          <input type="text" id="Peso" name="peso" required="">
          <input type="text" id="Altura" name="altura" required="">
<input type="text" id="Cintura" name="cintura" required="">
          <input type="text" id="Quadril" name="quadril" required="">
         <input type="submit" class="button-green" value="CALCULAR">     

         <?php
            if (isset ($_POST)) {
                $peso = $_POST['peso'];
                $altura = $_POST['altura'];
                $idade = $_POST['idade'];
                $cintura = $_POST['cintura'];
                $quadril = $_POST['quadril'];
                $conta1 = $altura * $altura;
                $conta2 = $peso / $conta1;
                $resultado = number_format($conta2, 2, ".", ",");

                $contaIAC1 = $altura * $altura * $altura;
                $contaIAC2 = sqrt($contaIAC1);
                $contaIAC3 = $quadril / $contaIAC2;
                $contaIAC4 = $contaIAC3 - 18;
                $resultadoIAC = number_format($contaIAC4, 2, ".", "," );

                $contaRCQ = $cintura / $quadril;
                $resultadoRCQ =  number_format($contaRCQ, 2, ".", ",");

            ?> 
        </form>
```

O `if` que quero é tipo assim:

```
 <?php
if(BOTÃO RADIO MASC APERTADO){


               if ($resultado < 17) {
            echo '<b style="color:#FEEE00;">Muito abaixo do peso</b>';}
    }

    if(BOTÃO RADIO FEMI APERTADO){
                if ($resultado < 15) {
            echo '<b style="color:#FEEE00;">Muito abaixo do peso</b>';}
    }
?>
```

Comment: O name do radio deve ser o mesmo

Comment: @rray obrigado pela dica

Answer (score 3):

O `name` do radio deve ser o mesmo, diga que seja mudado para `sexo` o que vai mudar apenas é o valor e não nome.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);


    if($_POST['sexo'] == 'masculino'){
        echo 'conta do masculino';
    }else{
        echo 'conta do feminimo';
    }

    echo '<br> valor marcado: '. $_POST['sexo'];

?>

<form action="#" method="post">
    masculino: <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="masculino"> <br>
    feminino: <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="feminino"> <br>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: vlw amigo deu certo :)

Comment: @kaiquemix, se resolveu o problema poderia marcar a reposta como aceita? se puder ver => [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/91)

Comment: @kaiquemix É importante para o site que as perguntas tenham uma resposta aceita (após serem resolvidas, claro). Para isso é só você clicar no sinal de ✓, que existe em toda resposta, bem abaixo da caixa de votação (veja o link que o rray passou). Ah, e votar também é importante. Não deixe de fazer o [tour] para entender como o site funciona, e aprender a explorar esta ferramenta de aprendizado incrível que é o SOpt.